# How to link a Component to react-bootstrap Navbar

Tags: react-navigation, react-bootstrap

I can navigate to {Home} component using "react-router" like this:

```
import { Route } from "react-router";
<Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
```

I would like to navigate to {Home} component using "react-bootstrap/Navbar" instead? Existing example provide only code like this

```
<Navbar.Collapse>
      <Nav>
        <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
```

I don't understand how to modify this code to use the existing {Home} component?
Please help
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

And make sure to import Link

> import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

```
                    <Nav className="mr-auto">
                        <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/create-order" >
                            Create Order
                        </Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/update-profile" >
                            Update Profile
                        </Nav.Link>
                       
                    </Nav>
```

You can use **as** property to change the type of the NavLink item and **to** property to set the path.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link} from "react-router-dom";

<Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
<Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
<Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
<Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
<Nav className="mr-auto">
<Nav.Link href="/home">Home</Nav.Link>
<Route exact path="/home" component={HomeComponent} />
</Nav>
</Navbar.Collapse>
</Navbar>
```

Comment: Suppose I have a component {Home}. How to navigate to this component using react-bootstrap? Please provide a code if possible